# How is an xml column stored in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-column

I try to understand how SQL Server 2008 store xml columns in an attempt to estimate table size in our product.

I'm using `DATALENGTH(xml_column)` to run some test and results are disturbing :

```
Xml document length | Datalength | Bytes per character
175                 | 366        | 2.09
15                  | 38         | 2.53
314                 | 414        | 1.31
```

Obviously, the xml column type is not a `nvarchar(max)` in disguise, as I've read somewhere.

It's probably compacted and stored as binary, but a can't find how anywhere.

Can someone explain me how is an xml column stored in SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by [rene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene), SQL Server 2008 uses the [MS-BINXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee208875%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - a compact binary format - to store the content of xml columns.

Answer (score 7):

An XML column is stored in a "compact binary format".

I doubt that Microsoft will give you any more detail than that.

Comment: And it's important to know it's a "tokenized" format, e.g. Microsoft guarantees to give back a **semantically** identical XML - but they do not guarantee the textual representation of the XML (e.g. MS will switch `<empty></empty>` to `<empty />` upon returning from their XML column, and as far as I know, there's no way to control that behavior. Don't rely on getting back a textually identical XML from SQL Server ....

Comment: Isn't compact binary format the same as [ms-binxml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee208875(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I have no idea if it's the same or not - and no interest, either. For all I care, it can change from one day to the next day, as long as it doesn't break anything.

Comment: @rene, this is a great document and it answers my question.